# Dynamic tablayout with viewpager2

Tags: android

I am working on e-commerce app project that has tablayout with a tab for each category and viewpager2 to show products of that speisfic category. and i use single fragment to create instances according to the number of categories that i get from remote server.

my problem is when i create instance from fragment i need to pass the position of that tab and when i log it from the fragment i get these cases:
somtimes logs print the right position
somtimes logs print 2 or 3 position
and sometimes logs don't print anything

can any one explain what is happening

Comment: A view pager usually preloads the fragment to the left (if any) and the fragment to the right (if any) of the current fragment. You can disable this behaviour by setting the offscreenLimit property of the view pager. Be careful, however, because you are effectively disabling eager loading and the user might notice this depending on your UX requirements.

Comment: Is there any better soluation other than disabling offscreenLimit ?

Comment: You can create a shared view model (or similar component) that has the knowledge of the currently displayed fragment position and does the loading of the actual fragment data or informs the view model of a particular fragment that it should start loading.